# What is the name of the Scottish Brewery that makes Nanny State beer?

Tags: breweries

I have a friend who is a fellow beer aficionado who told me about a brewery in Scotland that produced a beer that had such as high ABV that the government said it couldn't be produced because that technically categorized it as a liquor.

In retaliation the brewery came out with a beer named Nanny State that had such a low ABV that it couldn't be taxed by the government as alcohol. I have not been able to find the name of the brewery. Is anyone familiar with this story and/or the name of the brewery in question?

Comment: Eric is spot on.... Same company, I was just at the Columbus OH location a few hours ago : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Beer Advocate](https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/16315/53885/) the brewery is BrewDog.

Balmacassie Drive
Balmacassie Commercial Park
Ellon, Scotland, AB41 8BX
United Kingdom

There also seems to be a [BrewDog](https://shopusa.brewdog.com) in Ohio which also makes Nanny State beer. I think they are the same company.

Comment: Thank you Eric. I am familiar with BrewDog in the US, but didn't realize they are related to the Scottish brewery of the same name.